Visual studio 2022 - creates an empty project react from my own template
I would like to create my own template for react project.
In visual studio I created a new project from "Standalone typescript React project". From this project I create a template using

Project > Export template.
Subsequently, if I create a new project and select my created template, the project is created, but there is only the "*.esproj" file in it and nothing else.

I tried creating my template directly from the created project without any modifications. I have spent several hours looking for this problem but everything leads to other problems.
